# Why is only one result being returned

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

Python and vsCode, using google maps API
I have copied a program from a person on the internet to find all the businesses in my local area, but the returned data doesn't seem correct.

I first tried to search by keyword, and this returned lots of results, but not the type of business I wanted. I deleted this variable, and instead used an `opennow` variable. This returned only one result, and it was the town I had searched in, not a business. Could you have a look through the code and see if I have gone wrong?

The [API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com?project=perfect-precept-373715)

```
map_client = googlemaps.Client(API_KEY)

location = (54.970121, -2.101585)
distance = (1)
business_list= []

response = map_client.places_nearby(
    location=location,
    radius=distance,
)

business_list.extend(response.get('results'))
next_page_token = response.get('next_page_token')

while next_page_token:
    time.sleep(2)
    response = map_client.places_nearby(
        location=location,
        radius=distance,
        opennow=True,
        page_token=next_page_token
    )
    business_list.extend(response.get('results'))
    next_page_token = response.get('next_page_token')

df = pd.DataFrame(business_list)
df['url'] = 'www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:' + df['place_id']
df.to_excel('Toby Buisness.xlsx', index=False)
```

Thanks very much

Comment: You need to use `opennow=True` in the first query before the loop.

Comment: Are you by any means storing the data on your excel? I hope you're only storing place_IDs or coordinates(for 30 days) because that would be against their ToS. https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/#:~:text=5.4-,Caching,-.%20Customer%20can%20temporarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Radius for Nearby Search is too small for it to search anything else

I hope you take time to **read** the [Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview) and also the [Python Client Library](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html#googlemaps.Client.places_nearby) for Google Maps to better understand the code you copied.

Now the reason why it is only returning a single result, is because you have this: `distance = (1)`. This variable is used on your response as the value for the parameter `radius` on your `map_client.places_nearby`.

If you read the [Python Client Library](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html#googlemaps.Client.places_nearby), it says there:

> *radius (int) – Distance in meters within which to bias results.*

And looking at your code, this means that your radius for search is only at `1 meter`. Which explains why you are only returning a **single result** because ***no other place is in range except the place within its 1 meter range***, and if you have not specified any `type`, of course it will return the name of the vicinity that it is in. In your case, Hexham UK.

So I tried your code and used a radius of `1000 meters` and got more than 1 result. Here's the sample code:

```
import googlemaps

map_client = googlemaps.Client('YOUR_API_KEY_HERE')

location = '54.970121, -2.101585'
distance = 1000
business_list = []

response = map_client.places_nearby(
    location=location,
    radius=distance,
    type='restaurant'
)

business_list.extend(response.get('results'))

print(len(business_list))
```

Like I said before, please read the documentation because the parameter you used `opennow` is invalid and the correct one is `open_now`. Also you can try to use `type` parameter I used on my example to search for specific results.

Here's a link to the list of types that you can use on Nearby Search: [Table 1 Place Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table1).

Lastly, please make sure that your use case is within the bounds of their Terms of Service (In the case of scraping/caching Google Maps Data) to avoid problems with your app in the future. As I am not a legal expert, I suggest you take time to read their terms in these links: [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:%7E:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services.) / [Places API Specific Terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/#:%7E:text=non%2DGoogle%20map.-,5.4%20Caching,-.%20Customer%20can%20temporarily).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I now have working code!